# How to get invoice item list using sql query?

Tags: magento2, invoice

I am using **magento 2** and how can I get **list of items** on specific invoice?
I tried sql query with `sales_invoice` and `sales_invoice_item` table, but I couldn't get it. There are 2 same rows because of the sub-item(matrix item)
Please give some tips. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For resolved this ***sub items issue***, you need to take those  `entity_id` whose  ***order_item_id's  sales_item table's  parent_item_id is null***.

This two tables have a relation via  **`sales_invoice_item.order_item_id=sales_order_item.item_id`**

**So, can run below query**

```
SELECT * FROM `sales_invoice_item` as invoice_item, sales_order_item as order_item 
where invoice_item.order_item_id = order_item.item_id and order_item.parent_item_id is null
and invoice_item.parent_id = [INVOICE_ID]
```

Comment: How to get last year's order invoiced product list? @Amit